# Bigquery SQL Regex - Either start/end of string or not followed by/following any alphabet

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I want to find if a string (already lowercase) contains an exact word. It can be anywhere within the string. For example, let's say the word is `pot`.

I initially used

```
regexp_contains(lower(string), "^.*[^a-z]pot[^a-z].*$")
```

But this is unable to catch cases where pot comes at the start/end of the string. In my understanding `[^a-z]` needs to match something other than alphabets and for start/end cases it is not able to find anything.

So, I added `*` to make sure that even if there is no alphabet it is ok.

```
regexp_contains(lower(string), "^.*[^a-z]*pot[^a-z]*.*$")
```

But then it match cases where `pot` is a part of another larger word for eg. `honeypot` etc.

I don't think this problem is restricted to Bigquery SQL's `regexp_contains`.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please post few samples of input and expected output for making question more clear, thank you.

Comment: try this `REGEXP_CONTAINS(value, r"\bpot\b")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below example

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 'pot asdf' sentence union all 
  select 'rtui pot' union all 
  select 'rtui pot dfgrert' union all 
  select 'sdpot potdf lkpotij' union all 
  select 'fjkhgsiejur sldkkr'
)
select sentence
from `project.dataset.table`
where regexp_contains(lower(sentence), r'\bpot\b')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works using Bigquery UI. However, when I pass the same query to BQ from a jupyter notebook using `pands.read_gbq`, it doesn't work. 
I am using 
`if(regexp_contains(lower(string), r'(\blot\b|\bcot\b)'), 1, 0) is_pot_or_cot` 
and in UI some rows have 1 and some have 0s as expected but the dataframe fetched from jupyter noteboook has all 0s for column `is_pot_or_cot`.

Comment: How should I pass the above regex pattern in bigquery SQL from a python client? @Mikhail

Answer (score 0):

```
regexp_contains(lower(string), "^.*[^a-z]pot[^a-z].*$|^pot[^a-z].*$|^.*[^a-z]pot$|^pot$")
```